# Get CAN bitrate

Tags: c++, c++11, can-bus, netlink, socketcan

I want to read the currently configured CAN bitrate of my socketcan socket in C++.

I can see the bitrate with `ip -det link show can0`:

```
9: can0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
    link/can  promiscuity 0 
    can state ERROR-ACTIVE restart-ms 100 
    bitrate 1000000 sample-point 0.750 
    tq 125 prop-seg 2 phase-seg1 3 phase-seg2 2 sjw 1
    pcan_usb: tseg1 1..16 tseg2 1..8 sjw 1..4 brp 1..64 brp-inc 1
    clock 8000000
```

The bitrate was set via `/etc/network/interfaces`, but the user could manually change it.

libsocketcan seems to only support setting the bitrate, but not reading it.

The [code of `iproute2` that produces the output above](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/ip/iplink_can.c#L229) uses rtnetlink.

How could I use libnetlink to read the corresponding attribute? Or is there another way of reading the current bitrate?

Answer (score 4):

For now, I went with intepreting the output of a system call to `ip -det link show can0 | grep bitrate | awk '{print $2}'`, which is ugly but works.

Surely there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: It is at least a "useless use of grep". `ip -det link show can0 | awk '/bitrate/ {print $1}'`. I could not find the bitrate in `/sys/` either.

Comment: ```ip -det link show can0 | awk '/bitrate/ {print $1 "=" $2}'```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [can_get_bittiming()](https://lalten.github.io/libsocketcan/Documentation/html/group__extern.html#ga17ad92ba42f74a9e5fe23e9383336e3a) to get the set bitrate.